# Swift 3 | Get Bundle from his name or nib file

Tags: ios, swift3, bundle, init, nib

I'm developing a dynamic App where files can be in different modules. For example I have a Bundle "MODNews" and a Bundle "MODSpecific", I can have the ViewController file in the Bundle "MODNews" and the Nib file in the Bundle "MODSpecific".

To get the bundle for the ViewController I can do :

```
let bundle = Bundle.init(for: NSClassFromString("MODNews.MyClass")!)
```

But for the Nib, I can't find a way to get it, since the nib needs the bundle to be initialized I think this is not possible but maybe there is a way ?

In last option, I have the Bundle name here "MODSpecific", is it also possible to init a Bundle with this information ?

I use Swift3 but if you have a solution in a previous version or Objective-C I take it ;)

This is what I have for now :

```
    public static func getViewControllerForName (module: String, controller: String) -> UIViewController {

            let controllerString: String = Utils.getController(moduleString: module, controllerString: controller)
            let view: (Bundle, String) = Utils.getView(viewString: controller)

            let viewClass = NSClassFromString(controllerString) as! UIViewController.Type

            let viewController = viewClass.init(nibName: view.string, bundle: view.bundle) //Here I need the bundle from the viewClass found
            return viewController
        }

  static func getController (moduleString: String, controllerString: String) -> String {

            // Check if a specific controller exists
            let specificControllerString: String = specificAppName + "." + Constants.specificString + controllerString

            if (NSClassFromString(specificControllerString) != nil) {
                    // A specific controller exists, we get it
                    return specificControllerString
            }
            else {
                    // No specific found, we get the module controller
                    return moduleString + "." + controllerString
            }
        }

    static func getView (viewString: String) -> (Bundle, String) {

            // For Xib we do not need module !
            // Here I need something to get the bundle for current viewName, for example : getBundle(forResource: viewString, ofType: "nil")
            return (Bundle, String)
        }
```

TY

Comment: I need more context. I build something like this. We created a class to wrap the bundle, and used a system to create the wrapper, but it still needed the file URL to the bundle.

Comment: Hi @JefferyThomas I updated my question with some code explaining what I'm trying to do, I hope this is more clear.

Comment: What is the actual issue you are running in? `init(for:` shlould work imo. Else try: `let bundle = Bundle(identifier: "BundleID")`

Comment: I think `let bundle = Bundle(identifier: "com.XX.MODNews")` only works for current workspace. I need to check also in PODs. The actual issue is that I need to get the bundle for a given nib. The nib can be everywhere, in the current project or in a pod.